# Visual Studio Code IDE for Mac shows warnings on React JSX

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I'm having a go at React and I'm using Visual Studio Code IDE. The problem I'm having is that it's throwing highlighting errors when returning HTML elements in the render method. I've attached a picture to illustrate. I'm aware of the `jsconfig.json` file but I don't know what I should add to hide these highlighting warnings.

[image]

Comment: Try adding to the compileroptions: `"react": jsx`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but not working. Heres my jsconfig.json file {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "system",  
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators" : true,
        "react": "jsx"
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, other way around: `"jsx": "react" `

Comment: Sometimes, compiling sources `CTRL+B` can hide thes warnings

Comment: thanks again but still the same problem

Comment: Ow, You might need `(` and `)` in your render function, so `render(){ return (<h1>...</h1>); }` See: [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Comment: again thanks but still no luck. I think this is a visual studio code IDE problem not a react problem directly. I can get the code to compile fine it just looks like a mess in the editor.

Comment: What does the error actually say when you hover it?

Comment: it changes depending on what I hover. If I hover on <h1> then: cannot find name h1, 'Flux' cannot find name Flux etc...

Comment: I think I found the problem. I created a test app. When I name the file `app.js` I get comparable errors. If you are writing React, the file extension has to be `.jsx`. So basically, what is your file extension?

Comment: I added an answer with screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React files need a `jsx` extension for VS Code to highlight them correctly.

I attached screenshots to show. The first one is with `js` extension. This looks comparable to your screenshot.
[image: JS extension for file]

Note that with the second I renamed the file to `.jsx` and the highlighting is correct
[image: JSX extension]

Comment: Apart from above steps we can also use this extention https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.js-is-jsx which instructs editor to treat JS as JSX. i.e. still we can use .js instead .jsx